# How to find the limits of a triple integral converted to spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Find the integration limits of $\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9 - x^2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9 - x^2 - y^2}} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}{1 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2} dz dy dx$ in spherical coordinates.

So I know the integral will end up looking something like $\iiint_{}{} \frac{\rho^3}{1 + \rho^4} \sin \phi d \rho d \theta d \phi$, but I have no idea how to convert the limits. I know $0 < x < 3, \sqrt{9 - x^2} = y$ and $\sqrt{9 - x^2 - y^2} = z$, but how do I write $x, y,$ and $z$ in terms of $\rho, \theta,$ and $\phi$?

Comment: Note I edited my answer just now, I forgot to add one more transformation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to figure out what solid we're integrating over. In order to do this, in my opinion, it's easiest to try and graph out what the solid looks like.

First note that $z$ ranges from $0 \to \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$, $y$ ranges from $0 \to \sqrt{9-x^2}$ and finally $x$ ranges from $0 \to 3$, as you noted above. To begin with let's look a the range of $x$. From this we get the line segment from $x=0$ to $x=3$. Now let's incorporate the $y$ condition into our picture, while still ignoring the $z$ condition. If you think about the equation
$$
y = \sqrt{9-x^2}
$$
you will notice that this is the part of a circle centered at the origin with radius $3$ in the first and second quadrants. Combining this with the requirement that $x : 0 \to 3$ we get the surface described by the $x,y$ boundary conditions to be the quarter of a circle of radius $3$ centered at the origin in the first quadrant.

Lastly let's incorporate the $z$ conditions. Now imagining the surface described by $z = \sqrt{9 - x^2 - y^2}$ can be a bit hard but with some intuition we can see that this is the surface of the sphere centered at the origin with a radius of $3$ in the portion of space where $z$ is positive. Combining with the conditions above, we must have that $x,y\ge0$ as well so that this is the volume of the sphere with radius $3$ in the octant with $x,y,z\ge 0$.

Now we can move on to describing this surface with spherical coordinates. One can see with a bit of intuition that this is described by:
$$
\rho: 0 \to 3 \\
\phi: 0 \to \pi/2 \\
\theta: 0 \to \pi/2
$$

Now using a few transformations from spherical to cartesian coordinates we can see that the integrand transforms into:
$$
\frac{\rho}{1+\rho^4}
$$
And finally we need to transform our differentials, in spherical coordinates we have the volume element of:
$$
\mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} y \, \mathrm{d} z \to \rho^2 \sin \theta \, \mathrm{d} \rho \, \mathrm{d} \phi \, \mathrm{d} \theta
$$
so in the end we get the final integral:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^3 \frac{\rho}{1+\rho^4} \rho^2 \sin \theta \, \mathrm{d} \rho \, \mathrm{d} \phi \, \mathrm{d} \theta
$$

Answer (score 2):

If you make the graph of the solid, then you see the  limits  more easy, first draw the region in the plane $x-y$, how $0\leq x \leq 3$ and $0\leq y \leq \sqrt{9-x^2}$ then:

[image]

Now how $0\leq z\leq \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$ this is a one eighth of the sphere with radius 3, in the first octant of the space $x-y-z$.

[image]

The limits are $0\leq \rho\leq 3$,  $0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2$ and $0\leq \phi\leq \pi/2$